# Is this sentence grammatically correct despite using multiple tenses?

Tags: tenses

The sentence in question:

> Technology will advance, but thoughts on friends and lovers never change.

To my native ear it sounds reasonable, but a ESL friend feels it is not. Is it? Why or why not?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. Some ESL teachers  apparently lay it down as a rule that you can't use more than one tense in a sentence. Naturally, it's nonsense, but it does keep the students from making certain kinds of mistakes, and using lots of kinds of sentences. There are hundreds of such zombie rules, which you can find here very easily by looking at questions which start with "I know". What follows is almost always something constraining their English in unnatural ways.

Comment: Incidentally, there's only one tense in the sentence -- present tense. English doesn't have a future tense.

Comment: Why does your friend think this is not "reasonable"? Unless he tells you we can only say "seems all right to us" (or not) but we cannot address his grammatical objection.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question that is in front of me and I will try to answer it. Why should a sentence not deal with events in the past, present and future? The alternative would be to split sentences unnaturally and make prose staccato: “I have read your question. It is in front of me. I will try to answer it.”

Your example starts with a simple assertion about the future and continues with a second clause that makes a general assertion about the persistent nature of relationships. The use of the conjunction “but” invites a comparison of the two assertions. Were the sentence split it would be difficult to suggest the required comparison that places future change in the context of a persostent truth.